# Wanting to Delete a pass onwers account on iphone 4

Tags: iphone

Hi there i have recently purchased a iPhone from my cousin, whom had purchased it from trade me.When my cousin purchased it he couldn't download apps as it was still logged under the pass owner (cloud,apple id account).my cousin emailed him asking for his password so we can delete the account but he has not yet replied well over 2 weeks!!are u able to help me please???

Comment: We'd like to help you, but can't guess at some specifics.  What exact screen is showing an error message. Can you navigate to the settings app and choose reset, erase all content and settings?

Comment: Here are some specific questions you need to answer for us to help you: 1. What version of iOS is it running? It's listed under Settings>General>About This matters a lot if it is iOS 7 and Find My iPhone is enabled. 2. Do you have a Mac or PC running the current version of iTunes and the USB docking cable? You will need this. If it's running iOS 7 and Find My iPhone is enabled under Settings>iCloud you may be out of luck. That configuration is a new security mode that will resist attempts to use all the device's features and reset attempts. We need to know more.

Answer (score 1):

you can restore your iPhone [how to restore](http://www.wikihow.com/Restore-an-iPhone). This is the fast and easy way that all previous data it is delete. On step 3 you don't back up